# Django url configuration by groups of data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I need to create month based views. I can filter my entry items by month and I can display them on an html page. What I am having a hard time doing is only showing which month's data you select from the main page. So for example, if you click on November, it takes you to a page that only shows November's items, and so on. Do I need a specific url config for this? I'm hoping there is a simpler way to do this rather than creating a view for every month and then creating each month's url...

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    url(r'entry/list/?P<month_here>$', views.EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
class EntryListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'argent/index_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        mth = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # ENTRY BY MONTH

        # January17
        mth['January17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-1-1', '2017-1-31'))

        # February17
        mth['February17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-2-1', '2017-2-28'))

        return ctx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse args from url. This above will add in your view a quer-param of name "month", which should be one word (\w+ regex)

```
url(r'entry/list/(?P<month>\w+)$', views.EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list')
```

and then in get_context_data you should have this in your kwargs:

```
month = self.kwargs.get('month')
```

then add logic which parse your args then return proper queryset.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    mth = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # ENTRY BY MONTH
    month = self.kwargs.get('month')

    # January17
    if month == 'january:
      mth['January17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-1-1', '2017-1-31'))
    elif month == 'february':
      # February17
      mth['February17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-2-1', '2017-2-28'))

    return mth
```

and for multiple years you can also add some for-clausule which build your params like:

```
for year in range(2016, 2019):
    mth["{}{}_qs".format(month.title(), str(year)[-2:])] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=("{}-1-1".format(year), "{}-1-31".format(year))
# this will add you a 'January16_qs', 'January17_qs', 'January18_qs' variables if month is 'january'
```

Comment: This is great! Thankyou. I'm hitting one snag though. Whenever I click on the link for January, it still shows all my items, and not just the items for January. This is how my template tag looks:  `<a href="{% url 'argent:entry-list' 'january' %}"><h3>{{ ctx.month }} {{ ctx.year }}</h3></a>`. Anything look off to you?

Comment: if you use mth['variable_name'] you will have in your template this queryset stored as 'variable_name' - your main queryset (usually 'objects') are unchanged (contains all items, returned from your get_queryset() method.

Try move this logic from `get_context_data()` (which should be used to add additional data to context) to `get_queryset()` method (which is default assigned to 'objects' variable (or other if you specified `context_objects_name` variable).

Comment: But if you need have queryset which contains only queryset, which have januaries from different years you need add multiple filters in get queryset like:
`return Entry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=('2017-1-1', '2017-1-31') | Q(date__range=('2016-1-1', '2016-1-31'))` look at: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). In `get_queryset` you can get params from url , for example, via `self.request.GET['month' ]`

Comment: sorry, my mistake in last comment - not `self.request.GET['month']` but by `self.kwargs['month']`

Comment: This is really good information. I seem to be stuck though, I can't get passed an error `get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'month'`, even though my `get_context_data()` looks like this: `def get_context_data(self, month, **kwargs):
        month = kwargs.get('month')
        ctx = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`. If I run it like this: `def get_context_data(self,  **kwargs):
        month = kwargs.get('month')
        ctx = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` it passes the month in the url but does not show any data.

Comment: and how look your url() to this view?

Comment: The url looks good. It shows 'November' in the url: `/tracker/entry/list/November`. `url(r'entry/list/(?P<month>\w+)$', views.EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list')`

Comment: I ask about declaration in urls.py file :)

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon. `url(r'entry/list/(?P<month>\w+)$', views.EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list')`

Comment: first - if you use month in method header, then you need no kwargs.get. I'm not sure, why is not working not, but, for now, simply remove month from header: `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): month = kwargs.get('month')` <- you will get month from kwargs here

Comment: *one big mistake, sorry. With header will not works if you not override method, which tell this one.

remove 'month' from header, use self.kwargs.get('month') (simple kwargs.get('month') will also not work without other modifications).

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I really appreciate all of your help. I'll post the full solution as an answer, unless you would prefer to. Thanks again!

Comment: ok, I changed mistakes in my answer, now should be correct at all.